# How can I enter text in one screen and show it in another?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get text fields to save the inputs I have in them.  Then I'm trying to load the text that was saved in another screen within the same app.

Right now I have the texts fields showing up, then when I hit a button they display in a new screen but they don't save they just get sent.

Comment: It's best to include code samples in your questions, so we can see what you are doing. But unless you explicitly save and reload data, Activities lose all session data (everything change by the user).

Comment: It's also good to make the question title meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to save the data explicitly and load the data explicitly in onCreate or onResume.  There's a couple methods to do this (write it to a file, use a databse, SharedPreferences, etc).  For you the best way would probably be to send those text strings as named extras in the intent, and read them from the intent on the second activity.  So activity1 would call intent.putExtra("textfield1",value)  and activity2 would call textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("textfield1",""))

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
   Intent i=new Intent(this,ActivityName.class);  
    i.putExtra("key_to",text);
    startActivity(i);
```

Note that when you put an extra value, it is stored in key value pairs, hence in your target activity you extract it like this:

```
String text=(String)this.getIntent().getExtras().get("key_to");
```

And also, all these are written in the non-static methods of the activity, if you want to access it in static methods, use `getBaseContext()` instead of `this` while initializing the `Intent`